# Retrieving data from a form in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i am currently trying to get data from a form in a view to my controller, i'm sending it a list of object and my goal is to get the one that have been modified by having multiple form. The probleme here is that i don't get anything back from the view, just null values.

```
@model List<Connection_User>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count ; i++)
{
using(Html.BeginForm("DBLogin","User", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete ="off"}))
{
    <fieldset>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @ConsoleV2.Resources.Strings.Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Username)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @ConsoleV2.Resources.Strings.Password
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model[i].Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Password)
    </div>   
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="@ConsoleV2.Resources.Strings.Valid" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}
}
```

and the prototype of my method in the controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DBLogin(Connection_User Logins)
{


        return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug or Glimpse to see what's being sent?

Comment: I have used Fiddler, and the data sended by the post is   `%5B0%5D.User_ID=30&%5B0%5D.DB_ID=0&%5B0%5D.Username=TT&%5B0%5D.Password=` I am expecting something without the %5B0%5D which is [x] corresping to the number of the index. How to get it in the right way ?

Comment: Can you please specify how your model looks like

Comment: It's generated from a database model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `foreach` instead of `for`

```
@foreach(var modelItem in Model)
{
using(Html.BeginForm("DBLogin","User", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete ="off"}))
{
    <fieldset>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @ConsoleV2.Resources.Strings.Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(item => modelItem.Username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => modelItem.Username)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @ConsoleV2.Resources.Strings.Password
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(item => modelItem.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item=> modelItem.Password)
    </div>   
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="@ConsoleV2.Resources.Strings.Valid" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}
}
```

Comment: This the post data sended catched by Fiddler :
`item.User_ID=30&item.DB_ID=0&item.Username=TT&item.Password=stuff`
It is still not giving me anything back in my post method.

Comment: change your controller attribute to item like this: `public ActionResult DBLogin(Connection_User item)`

Comment: It works Yorgo, thanks a lot yorgo, i found an other solution before reading yours but it's almost the same, it's to use [Bind(Prefix = "item")] before the class name in the parameter 
i.e. `public ActionResult DBLogin([Bind(Prefix = "item")]Connection_User randomname)` Thanks a lot again !